# Why Xcode's interface builder creates UIView as "phone"

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, subclass, xib

I want to create custom subclass of UIView - to add there some labels, images etc. I don't like using Storyboards and Xibs, but I have to use them now in my new project. I can't figure out why for god's sake is Xcode's interface builder displaying UIView in view hierarchy as "phone" instead of just view with some frame.

I've tried to create Xib file using this:

new file > empty ( under user interfaces section ) > name xib file

And I got this:

[image]

after adding the UIView into the view hierarchy I get this:

[image]

But I want it to be simple view where I can insert any subviews. Or is this just a view and interface builder is displaying it in this stupid way? Because I'm used to seeing custom UIView subclasses like this:

[image]

This last screenshot is from the same project, but it's a subclass of UIBUtton and it was created by someone else. Thanks for help / explanation.

FYI: I'm using Xcode 10.3

Comment: Can't reproduce. And why did you start with Empty? Why didn't you start with View?

Comment: @matt: when I started with View, it was same. Nullable's anwser describes how to achieve what I asked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a habit problem and does not affect the use.

If you must look the same as before, you can set it on the far right.

`Show the Attributes inspector`->`Simulated Metrics` -> `Size` -> `Freeform`

[image]

Comment: This has been driving me crazy for some time. I wonder why will not just live as freedom. It feels more comfortable. Thanks for the share.